# Can anyone help me solve the error related to robot_description on parameter server?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, robot-description, robot-state-publisher, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error exactly is

```
[ERROR] [1546860953.191408064]: Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server
[rob_st_pub-6] process has died [pid 2696, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher robot_description:=spider_robot_description /joint_states:=/spider_joint_states __name:=rob_st_pub __log:=/home/microbot/.ros/log/63188c6c-1270-11e9-929e-2c6e85b13edd/rob_st_pub-6.log].
log file: /home/microbot/.ros/log/63188c6c-1270-11e9-929e-2c6e85b13edd/rob_st_pub-6*.log
```

I am beginner, from what  I have understood, I believe the error is caused because robot_state_publisher node can not fetch the robot_description in order to work with. But when I checked the parameter list using  command I could see the robot_description parameter in the list and also I could see the xml file created from xacro when I checked with  command. Now I am unsure about the reason behind this error. Here I am also attaching my control launch file,

```
<launch>

  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find spider_control)/config/spider_control.yaml" command="load"/>

  <!-- load the controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawnner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen" ns="/spider" args="joint_1_1_position_controller
                      joint_1_2_position_controller
                                          joint_1_3_position_controller
                                          joint_2_1_position_controller
                                          joint_2_2_position_controller
                                          joint_2_3_position_controller
                                          joint_3_1_position_controller
                                          joint_3_2_position_controller
                                          joint_3_3_position_controller
                                          joint_4_1_position_controller
                                          joint_4_2_position_controller
                                          joint_4_3_position_controller
                                          joint_5_1_position_controller
                                          joint_5_2_position_controller
                                          joint_5_3_position_controller
                                          joint_6_1_position_controller
                                          joint_6_2_position_controller
                                          joint_6_3_position_controller
                                          joint_7_1_position_controller
                                          joint_7_2_position_controller
                                          joint_7_3_position_controller
                                          joint_8_1_position_controller
                                          joint_8_2_position_controller
                                          joint_8_3_position_controller"/>

  <!-- convert joint states to TF transforms for rviz, etc -->
  <node name="rob_st_pub" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
  <remap from="robot_description" to="spider_robot_description" />
    <remap from="/joint_states" to="/spider_joint_states" />
    
  </node>

</launch>
```

Please help me find the reason behind this error. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312098/can-anyone-help-me-solve-the-error-related-to-robot_description-on-parameter-server-?/) by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-07**:
when i try to publish the joint angle using rostopic pub and position controllers, it returns saying publishing and latching for 3 seconds but I could not see any change with that particular joint on gazebo, is this related to the previous error aswell ? thank you

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-07**:
Thanks, I have solved that error. It is caused because in my control launch file I remapped the robot_description to spider_robot_description for my robot_state_publisher but when googled I came to know that robot_state_publisher by default looks for robot_description in parameter server.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2019-01-07**:
Great, you should post this as an answer, to help others with a similar problem! (you're allowed to 'answer your own question').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, I have solved that error. It is caused because in my control launch file I remapped the robot_description to spider_robot_description for my robot_state_publisher but when googled I came to know that robot_state_publisher by default looks for robot_description in parameter server. So if you happen to remap your robot_description for the node, then make sure your node searches for the same.

---

Originally posted by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) with karma: 96 on 2019-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2019-01-25**:
I would also suggest marking your answer as the correct one, with the little "check" button.